# Query to select data between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date-range

I have a `start_date` and `end_date`. I want to get the list of data in between these two dates. 
Can anyone help me pointing the mistake in my query.

```
select * from [dbo].[User] 
where Date between'2014-8-01' AND '2014-8-30'
```

There is no error but also the query doesn't return any records.

Comment: Well I'd start by adding a space after `between`, and using full `yyyy-MM-dd` format, i.e. `08` instead of `8` for the month. I realize it's unlikely to make a different, but give that a try to start with. What's the type of the `Date` field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proper casting is necessary

```
select * from [dbo].[User] 
    where CAST([Date] as DATE) between '2014-08-01' AND '2014-08-30'
```

Format for Date Passing as Parameter

```
'yyyy-MM-dd'
```

Comment: Presumably only if `Date` isn't the right type already... I've asked the OP to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Better to use >= and < and use time in your where clause instead of using CAST in where. Better performance.

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[User] 
    WHERE [Date] >= '2014-8-01 00:00:00'
    AND [Date] < '2014-8-31 00:00:00'
```